# Redis running on socket?

Tags: cache

Am I right to think that Redis should be configured with a TCP port to work with CiviCRM?

I would like to use the Unix socket option.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? I haven't tried but it looks like you could just set `define('CIVICRM_DB_CACHE_HOST', '/tmp/redis.sock');` in civicrm.settings.php (adjust file path as needed).

Comment: Defining CIVICRM_DB_CACHE_HOST as a socket does not work: Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for /run/redis/redis.sock failed: Name or service not known Redis.php:70

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the connect function in /vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Cache/Redis.php to use pconnect to connect via a socket:

```
public static function connect($config) {
    $socket = '/run/redis/redis.sock'; // Path to the Redis socket
    $pass = CRM_Utils_Constant::value('CIVICRM_DB_CACHE_PASSWORD');
    $id = implode(':', ['connect', $socket /* $pass is constant */]);
    if (!isset(Civi::$statics[__CLASS__][$id])) {
        $redis = new Redis();
        if (!$redis->pconnect($socket)) {
            // dont use fatal here since we can go in an infinite loop
            echo 'Could not connect to Redis server using socket';
            CRM_Utils_System::civiExit();
        }
        if ($pass) {
            $redis->auth($pass);
        }
        Civi::$statics[__CLASS__][$id] = $redis;
    }
    return Civi::$statics[__CLASS__][$id];
  }
```